# GoogleTest using cmake: Separating tests into .cpp and .h files

Tags: c++, c, cmake, googletest

I am not very familiar with C++, especially with make and building.

In my CMakeLists.txt, I have:

```
add_executable(example test_runner.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example gtest_main)

gtest_discover_tests(example)
```

Then in `test_runner.cpp` I have:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "sample_tests.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

And `sample_tests.h` is:

```
#ifndef PROJECTS_SAMPLE_TESTS_H
#define PROJECTS_SAMPLE_TESTS_H


#endif //PROJECTS_SAMPLE_TESTS_H
```

And sample_tests.cpp is:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "sample_tests.h"

TEST(sample_test_case, sample_test)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 2);
}
```

So, what is clear to me is that the issue here is that test_runner.cpp imports sample_tests.h, but sample_tests.h doesn't import sample_tests.cpp. However, from my understanding, .h files can't import .cpp files. I know that `sample_tests.cpp` is supposed to be implementing `sample_tests.h`, but I can't figure out how to actually link these together.

Is this something I need to configure in cmakelists.txt?

Comment: If you want `sample_tests.cpp` to be compiled as part of your program, just add ist to the list of files in the [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) command. You also may want to have a look on the basics of CMake, e.g. see [this tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/cmake/example/22391/-hello-world--with-multiple-source-files).

Comment: In addition to the comment of StanleyF, the header file `sample_tests.h` serves no purpose at all. Delete it and delete `#include "sample_tests.h"`.